# Combinatoric/Partitioning exercise Stardew Valley

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am playing a popular computer game called Stardew Valley. In the game, you can take a fruit/vegetable put it into a seed maker to get more seeds.

If I put 1 tomato into the seedmaker, itt can return me the following:

- 1 tomato seed
- 2 tomato seed
- 3 tomato seed
- 4 tomato seed

This had me thinking. If I give the seedmaker 5 tomato plants:

- how many ways can I get 13 seeds
- how many ways can I get 13 or more seeds?

This looks like a partitioning number theory problem. (how many ways can N  integers achieve a sum of X). However, what makes this more difficult is the stipulation that the integer =<4 since the seed maker can return a max of 4 seeds.

Any help is appreciated!

*Eventually, I would like to make the problem more difficult by asking the probability of getting 13 seeds given:*

- 1 tomato seed -20% chance
- 2 tomato seed - 40% chance
- 3 tomato seed -30% chance
- 4 tomato seed -10% chance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not planting the seeds and growing new tomatoes to plant, the generating function is:  $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)^5$ and you require the coefficient of the $x^{13}$ term.

Now the relevant parts of thirteen (and relevant percentages to the right) are:$$\begin{align}13 =&~ 4+4+3+1+1 & 12/10^5~&=(0.1)^2(0.3)(0.2)^2 
\\=&~ 4+4+2+2+1 & 32/10^5 ~&= (0.1)^2(0.4)^2(0.2) 
\\=&~ 4+3+3+2+1 & 72/10^5 ~&= (0.1)(0.3)^2(0.4)(0.2)
\\= &~ 4+3+2+2+2& 192/10^5 ~&= (0.1)(0.3)(0.4)^3
\\=&~ 3+3+3+3+1 & 162 /10^5 ~&= (0.3)^4(0.2) 
\\ = &~ 3+3+3+2+2 & 432/10^5 ~&= (0.3)^3(0.4)^2 \end{align}$$

... so the coefficient will be $\binom{5}{2,1,2}+\binom{5}{2,2,1}+\binom{5}{1,2,1,1}+\binom{5}{1,1,3}+\binom{5}{4,1}+\binom{5}{3,2}$

The count of ways to get exactly thirteen seeds from feeding 5 tomatoes to the machine is: $$\begin{align}~&2\binom{5}{2,2,1}+\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}+\binom{5}{3,1,1}+\binom{5}{3,2}
\\[1ex] =~& 2\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{5}{2}3!+\binom{5}{3}2!+\binom{5}{3}
\\[1ex] =~& \binom{5}{2}(6+6+2+1)
\\[1ex] =~& 150\end{align}$$

And the weighted probability will be: $$\begin{align}P(X=13)~=~&\dfrac{\binom{5}{2,1,2}12+\binom{5}{2,2,1}32+\binom{5}{1,2,1,1}72+\binom{5}{1,1,3}192+\binom{5}{4,1}162+\binom{5}{3,2}432}{10^5}\end{align}$$

---

That's the easy bit.   Now repeat the process for counts for from 14 to 20 tomatoes.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Can you explain how you got $10^5$ as the total possible number of outcomes? I would have thought the total possible outcomes as $4^5$ (5 events, 4 possible outcomes).

Comment: @bLunt No, its not the total number of outcomes. That *weighting* is from the percentages you gave: $\tfrac 2{10}$ for one, $\tfrac 4{10}$ for two, $\tfrac 3{10}$ for three, and $\tfrac 1{10}$ for four seeds. There are $\binom{5}{2,1,2}$ ways the machine can produce two lots of four, one lot of three, and two lots of one seeds, and the probability weighting of *each* of these individual outcomes is: $\tfrac{1^2\cdot 3\cdot 2^2}{10^5}$ . Put it together to get the probability of: $$\binom{5}{2,1,2}\dfrac{3\cdot 2^2}{10^5} ~=~ 0.003\,60$$ Then add the probability for other patterns .

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you.